# .htaccess redirects correctly but not the expected way

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I've an old website url

```
http://www.babycareadvice.com/babycare/general_help/article.php?id=93&0_id=1#591
```

which i want to redirects to

```
http://www.babycareadvice.com/article/detail/93
```

but it redirects to

```
http://www.babycareadvice.com/article/detail/93#591
```

how i remove this #591 part in url.
The code i've written in .htaccess is here

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /babycare/general_help/category\.php\?id=93]+)  [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(http://babycareadvice.com)? /article/detail/93? [R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below rule,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^babycare/general_help/article.php [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([\d]+)&0_id=1#591
RewriteRule ^ article/detail/%1 [R=301,L]
```

From what I know hash will not entertained by apache.

**Note:** I didn't tried it for now but similar rule worked for me.